Docker Compose on Windows 11 bind mount error: "service volume xxx[0] is missing a mount target"
I am running Docker v25.0.3 via Docker Desktop on Windows 11.  I cannot get my bind mount volume to work with Docker Compose.
My docker-compose.yaml looks like this:
version: '3'
services:
  oidc-server-mock:
    container_name: oidc-server-mock
    image: ghcr.io/soluto/oidc-server-mock:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      CLIENTS_CONFIGURATION_PATH: config/clients-config.json
    volumes:
      - type: bind
      - source: /mnt/c/Users/my/local/config/path
      - target: /config

It does work if, instead of using docker compose, I use docker run fom Powershell with the following parameters:
--mount type=bind,source=C:\my\local\config\path,target=/config
But for some reason docker compose doesn't like my file.
What I have tried:  I've tried different every imaginable path format suggested by online searches for my docker-compose.yml's -source parameter, both with and without double quotes surrounding the path.  Furthermore, I cannot find anything online where this specific error message "missing a mount target" is mentioned verbatim.

Have you tried C:\my\local\config\path as the source path?

@HansKilian yes I tried that and it gives the same error.  And if I wrap the path in double quotes, it gives the error yaml: line 13: did not find expected hexdecimal number.

You've declared three separate volumes: but each with only one of the required options.  If you delete the - on the last two lines, it will be one volume with three options.

Solution
Your syntax is incorrect:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
      - source: /mnt/c/Users/my/local/config/path
      - target: /config

This should instead be:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /mnt/c/Users/my/local/config/path
        target: /config

or in short format:
    volumes:
      - /mnt/c/Users/my/local/config/path:/config

Explanation
- in yaml indicates a list element. What you are basically doing with your current config is that you define 3 different volumes: one with only type, another with only source and a third with only target. The error refers to the first ([0]) element on the list.
The equivalent syntax error with docker run would be something like this:
docker run --mount type=bind --mount source=C:\my\local\config\path --mount target=/config

As a clearer example, if you would need a second volume, the correct syntax would be:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /mnt/c/Users/my/local/config/path
        target: /config
      - type: bind
        source: /foo
        target: /bar


This error will also arise if you have a space b/n volume mount and the target
For example:
....
    volumes:
      - /mnt/c/Users/my/local/config/path: /config
....

This code snippet will throw a similar error message. The solution is to remove the white space after :. So the correct value would look like
....
    volumes:
      - /mnt/c/Users/my/local/config/path:/config
....

